# Sorting elements by number parent-child relationship while looping through a list in c#

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have such a list;

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>
    {
        2,
        4,
        4,
        2,
        4,
        4,
        6,
        6,
        8,
        2,
        4
    };
```

and i want to list it as below

```
2
        4
        4
2
        4
        4
            6
            6
                8
2
        4
```

Please note that these are a dynamic list.
and the 2's are the main elements the 4's are the 2's child elements etc..

I've used this example for a simpler explanation, what I really want to do is list HTML elements by parent-child relationship with tag indexes.

What is the ideal way to list as in this solution?

Comment: So you just want to print the items with different indentation?

Comment: So your list contains only even numbers? Does it contain odd numbers?

Comment: Did you even try anything so far?

Comment: How this question is related to Blazor and EF Core?

Comment: yes I have a basic HTML class and it contains elements such as divs and p's and these elements are pulled from the database as a multiple of 2 according to the tagindex. To give an example, the event I want to get my hands on is as follows;
<div>
<other items, if any.>
<other items below, if any.>
</div>
I hope I was able to explain. @Magnus

Comment: As I said above, this was actually a simple explanation, I am doing the application with Blazor and I may have associated it with excitement. Sorry for that. and do i need to remove them?
@SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: new string('\t', n)?

Comment: yes, I put it in and out of loops with for, but there were problems every time.
@MakePeaceGreatAgain

Comment: yes they are all multiples of 2 @DotNetDeveloper

Comment: `Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, numbers.Select(item => item.ToString().PadLeft(number))));`

Comment: As for `List<int>` all we can do is to add padding (there's no way to detect if `2` is a parent / child of `4`). Please, provide an actual example (items with parent / child relation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is two ways.

Using `<pre>` and '\t':

```
@foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    <div class="d-flex flex-row"><pre>@(new string('\t',number))</pre>@number</div>
}
```

or

Using a render fragment of choice:

```
@foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        @for (var i = 0; i < number; i++)
            @SomeGap

        @number
    </div>
}
@code {
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>
    {
        ...
    };

    RenderFragment SomeGap => @<div>gap</div>;
    
}
```

You could extend the second method further by making the render fragment a parameter or static. In a hierarchical arrangement you could pass the depth as a parameter;

Answer (score 1):

Add indentation based on your values

```
var list = numbers
    .Select(i => new string('\t', i / 2 - 1) + i)
    .ToList();
```